# Custom flat-file "CMS" questions on standards

Tags: php, content-management-system, flat-file

I'm working on a simple custom "cms" - this is for a school that needs an easy to manage website for students to edit etc. Therefore I'm not using wordpress and other pre-built cms systems.

I'm about a few weeks into the project and I've got the system set up - however it's getting messy and bulky. Can someone help me understand how to set up a modular design to my system.

So far I have:

Upload system (Uploads into directories based on file type)
Page loader (Loads set pages into the framework)
User Mang. (Authorises access to systems and pages)

All I really need is an idea how to set this all up and maybe a demo - if someone can supply me with this info that would be great. Otherwise I'll just keep looking.

Cheers, Keiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading some tutorials out there. They will give a better idea for a simple CMS.

http://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/

http://www.intranetjournal.com/php-cms/

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/management-system-php

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it more.